# What is the difference between kubectl apply and kubectl replace

Tags: kubectl

I am learning Kubernetes recently, and I am not very clear about the difference between "kubectl apply" and "kubectl replace". Is there any situation that we can only use one of them?

Comment: This may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47369351/kubectl-apply-vs-kubectl-create

Comment: good read on subject: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/object-management/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [kubectl apply vs kubectl create?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47369351/kubectl-apply-vs-kubectl-create)

Answer (score 33):

I have written up a thorough explanation of the differences between apply, replace, and patch: [Kubernetes Apply vs. Replace vs. Patch](https://blog.atomist.com/kubernetes-apply-replace-patch/). It includes an explanation that the current top-ranked answer to this question is wrong.

Briefly, `kubectl apply` uses the provided spec to create a resource if it does not exist and update, i.e., patch, it if it does.  The spec provided to `apply` need only contain the required parts of a spec, when creating a resource the API will use defaults for the rest and when updating a resource it will use its current values.

The `kubectl replace` completely replaces the existing resource with the one defined by the provided spec. `replace` wants a *complete* spec as input, including read-only properties supplied by the API like `.metadata.resourceVersion`, `.spec.nodeName` for pods, `.spec.clusterIP` for services, and `.secrets` for service accounts. `kubectl` has some internal tricks to help you get that right, but typically the use case for `replace` is getting a resource spec, changing a property, and then using that changed, complete spec to replace the existing resource.

The `kubectl replace` command has a `--force` option which actually does not use the replace, i.e., `PUT`, API endpoint. It forcibly deletes (`DELETE`) and then recreates, (`POST`) the resource using the provided spec.

Answer (score 21):

**Updated Answer**

My original was rather controversial and I would even say now, in hindsight, half incorrect. So here is an updated answer which I hope will be more helpful:

- commands like kubectl `patch`, `replace`, `delete`, `create`, even `edit` are all imperative: they tell kubectl exactly what to do
- the kubectl `apply` command is OTOH "declarative" in that it tells kubernetes, here is a desired state (the yaml from the file provided to the apply command), now figure out how to get there: create, patch, replace the object, etc whatever it takes... you get the idea.

So the 2 commands are hugely different.

EG with `apply` you can give it just the changes you want: it will figure out what properties of the object need to be changed, and leave the other ones alone; if those properties are "immutable" (eg, the nodeName of a pod), it will complain, and if you then repeat the command with `--force`, it is smart enough to know to do the equivalent of a `replace --force`.

In general, you should favor `apply` (with `--force` when necessary), and only use the imperative commands when the declarative approach does not give the expected result (although I would love to see examples of this -- I'm guessing this would happen only when you would need several steps because of interdependencies that will have negative consequences if done with apply).

Comment: This does not seem to happen in practice. If I `kubectl apply` a new deployment with no replica count specified - it seems to default to `0` or `1`.

Comment: @Code you are right and there was quite a spread of votes (only 2/3 were up votes) so I updated my answer a few weeks ago, hopefully that makes it more useful

Comment: It would be best to delete the original answer section since it's incorrect.

Comment: @richvel removed original

Comment: if you update an answer and remove its original content, we lose track of the history and don't know whether a comment applies to the original or to the updated one

Comment: @AndreSoares: I agree but too late to fix. But luckily it's easy: only comments from Jan 25, 2021 and after relate to the current version of my answer. So only one comment is obsolete (the one by @ChrisStryczynski).

Answer (score 6):

The difference between `apply` and `replace` is similar to the difference between `apply` and `create`.

`create` / `replace` uses the [imperative](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/manage-kubernetes-objects/imperative-config/) approach, while `apply` uses the [declarative](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/manage-kubernetes-objects/declarative-config/) approach.

If you used `create` to create the resource, then use `replace` to update it. If you used `apply` to create the resource, then use `apply` to update it.

Note that both `replace` and `apply` require a complete spec, and both create the new resources first before deleting the old ones (unless `--force` is specified).

Comment: For a more thorough explanation and comparison, see [this section](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/object-management/) in the Kubernetes docs.

Comment: "Note that both replace and apply require a complete spec, and both create the new resources first before deleting the old ones (unless --force is specified)." This is the biggest take away here. Thank you 

Answer (score 6):

you can add option -v=8 when use kubectl, and you will find the log like this

```
apply --force
patch 422
delete 200
get 200
get 200
get 404
post 201

replace --force
get 200
delete 200
get 404
post 201
```

Answer (score 4):

`kubectl apply ..` will use various heuristics to selectively update the values specified within the resource.

`kubectl replace ...` will replace / overwrite the entire object with the values specified. **This should be preferred** as you're avoiding the complexity of the selective heuristic update. However some resources like ingresses/load balancers can't really be replaced as they're immutable.

Example of the heuristic update leading to non obvious operation: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/67135

Answer (score 3):

From: https://github.com/kubernetes/website/blob/master/content/en/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/manage-deployment.md

> **Disruptive updates**
>
> In some cases, you may need to update resource fields that cannot be
>   updated once initialized, or you may just want to make a recursive
>   change immediately, such as to fix broken pods created by a
>   Deployment. To change such fields, use `replace --force`, which deletes
>   and re-creates the resource.

Comment: I think this is more about the `--force` option than about `kubectl replace` itself, as can be seen with `kubectl replace --help`:
`--force=false: Delete and re-create the specified resource`.
The docs do not contain infomation about what distinguishes "kubectl replace" from "kubectl apply".