# How to use apply instead of create for deployment in Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes

I am trying to create a deployment declaratively, using `kubectl apply`. The below configuration is created just fine when I do

```
kubectl create -f postgres-deployment.yaml
```

but if I go

```
kubectl apply -f postgres-deployment.yaml
```

I am presented with the lovely error message:

> error: unable to decode "postgres-deployment.yaml": no kind
>   "Deployment" is registered for version "apps/v1beta1"

I have tried searching for an explanation to what this means but I cannot figure it out.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: postgres-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: postgres
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: postgres
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: postgres
        image: postgres:10.1
        ports:
        - containerPort: 5432
```

Comment: can you post the output for `kubectl version`

Comment: From `kubectl apply --help`: `To use 'apply', always create the resource initially with either 'apply' or 'create --save-config'`. So maybe try `kubectl create --save-config -f postgres-deployment.yaml` and then use `kubectl apply -f postgres-deployment.yaml`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [kubectl apply vs kubectl create?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47369351/kubectl-apply-vs-kubectl-create)

Answer (score 2):

Old Kubernetes versions supported the Deployment object on the `extensions/v1beta1` API group. [That is no longer the case](https://v1-9.docs.kubernetes.io/docs/api-reference/v1.9/#deployment-v1beta1-extensions).

For Kubernetes versions before 1.9.0 you should use the API group `apps/v1beta2`.

[In Kubernetes 1.9](https://v1-9.docs.kubernetes.io/docs/api-reference/v1.9/#deployment-v1-apps) and above you should use the API group `apps/v1`.

Comment: But why does `kubectl create` work and `kubectl apply` doesn't? I would expect that both fail when a wrong API version is used.

Comment: I'm just assuming here, but since `kubectl apply`is part of the declarative way of creating objects, it performs actions than eventually ensures the api group of the object being created is not deprecated. On the other hand `kubectl create` is part of the imperative way of creating objects, and so, in this way of managing objects, the object just gets created if the api group exists, even though is deprecated. I'd bet kubectl create would fail if you replace `apps/v1beta1` with "bananas".

Comment: Client Version or Server version?