# newbie - changed yaml - what to do to update k8s cluster with same

Tags: kubernetes

Let's say I have a deploymnet.yaml or PVC.yaml. I update the yaml file with some values. What should I do? Apply again? Sorry for newbie question I searched and went through documentation and came across rolling updates and record which I believe is further down the learning curve for me.

```
kubectl apply -f pvc.yaml # first run
```

Changes made to file

```
kubectl apply -f pvc.yaml # run again to update?
```

I created efs-provisioner without rbac and I believe pvc is in pending status because of it. So trying to update the yamls to accommodate the change.

Comment: see this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/47389305/1626280

Comment: @Amityo Thank you so much this is greatly helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, run again.

Kubernetes will take care of the rests.

Comment: Thank you so much for quick response. is it ideal to use apply for CI/CD purposes?

Comment: yes, you can. If you need blue/green deployment, then you need do some extra jobs.