# Kubernetes Declarative Management and Manual Commands risks

Tags: kubernetes

I understand the difference between Declarative and Imperative Management, well explained in this thread [kubectl apply vs kubectl create?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47369351/kubectl-apply-vs-kubectl-create) and in the official doc https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/manage-kubernetes-objects/declarative-config/

But my residual doubt is that even in the Declarative Management a (manual) command like

> kubectl scale

although persists further

> kubectl apply

commands still "won't survive" a cluster restart (since its configuration change is stored in the cluster store, like *etcd*), right? If so, shouldn't we make changes only to the

> object configuration file

and redeploy through

> kubectl apply

command? 
thanks

Comment: i also see some confusion around that - what recommendation you finally got ? It seems it is better to rely on version managment tools like git rather than leaving everything to the kubernetes -

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understand `kubectl scale` will change the `ReplicaSet` configuration object in `etcd`. So, it'll survive a restart.

However, you should store your configuration objects in a version control system (git). If you execute commands like `kubectl scale`, that won't update the copies stored in git. The next usage of those configuration files will override the values previously set.