# Kubernetes Exposing An Application - AWX Operator

Tags: kubernetes, ansible, ansible-awx

Hope you are all well,

I am currently trying to rollout the [awx-operator](https://github.com/ansible/awx-operator) on to a Kubernetes Cluster and I am running into a few issues with going to the service from outside of the cluster.

Currently I have the following services set up:

```
NAME                   TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)             AGE
awx                    NodePort    10.102.30.6      <none>        8080:32155/TCP      110m
awx-operator           NodePort    10.110.147.152   <none>        80:31867/TCP        125m
awx-operator-metrics   ClusterIP   10.105.190.155   <none>        8383/TCP,8686/TCP   3h17m
awx-postgres           ClusterIP   None             <none>        5432/TCP            3h16m
awx-service            ClusterIP   10.102.86.14     <none>        80/TCP              121m
kubernetes             ClusterIP   10.96.0.1        <none>        443/TCP             17h
```

I did set up a `NodePort` which is called `awx-operator`. I did attempt to create an ingress to the application. You can see that below:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: awx-ingress
spec:
  rules:
  - host: awx.mycompany.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: awx
            port:
              number: 80
```

When I create the ingress, and then run `kubectl describe ingress`, I get the following output:

```
Name:             awx-ingress
Namespace:        default
Address:
Default backend:  default-http-backend:80 (<error: endpoints "default-http-backend" not found>)
Rules:
  Host               Path  Backends
  ----               ----  --------
  awx.mycompany.com
                     /   awx:80 (10.244.1.8:8080)
Annotations:         <none>
Events:              <none>
```

Now I am not too sure whether the `default-http-backend:80` error is a red-herring as I have seen this in a number of places and they don't seem too worried about it, but please correct me if I am wrong.

Please let me know whether there is anything else I can do to troubleshoot this, and I will get back to you as soon as I can.

Comment: You can ignore default backend. You probably picked a wrong service/port for the ingress. Try `awx-service` with port `80` or `awx` with port `8080`.

Comment: Thanks for that I will try it now, but before I do. I have seen a couple of places that use `kubectl create` and not `kubectl apply` . What is the difference?

Comment: See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/47389305/11344502

Comment: Hi running the ingress on `awx-service` and on port 80 I get the following output when I run `kubectl get ingress`:

`NAME          CLASS    HOSTS               ADDRESS   PORTS   AGE
awx-ingress   <none>   awx.mycompany.com             80      72s`

I have a feeling the fact that the address is blank is the issue.

Answer (score 2):

You are right and the blank address is the issue here. In traditional *cloud* environments, where network load balancers are available on-demand, a single Kubernetes manifest suffices to provide a single point of contact to the NGINX Ingress controller to external clients and, indirectly, to any application running inside the cluster.

*Bare-metal* environments on the other hand lack this option, requiring from you a slightly different setup to offer the same kind of access to external consumers:

[image: Bare-metal environment]

This means you have to do some additional gymnastics to make the ingress work. And you have basically two main options here (all well described [here](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/baremetal/#bare-metal-considerations)):

- A pure software solution: [MetalLB](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/baremetal/#a-pure-software-solution-metallb)
- Over the [NodePort](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/baremetal/#over-a-nodeport-service) service.

What is happening here is that you basically creating a service type `NodePort` with selector that matches your ingress controller pod and then it's routes the traffic accordingly to your ingress object:

```yaml
# Source: ingress-nginx/templates/controller-service.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
  labels:
    helm.sh/chart: ingress-nginx-3.30.0
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 0.46.0
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
  name: ingress-nginx-controller
  namespace: ingress-nginx
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - name: http
      port: 80
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: http
    - name: https
      port: 443
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: https
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
```

Full nginx deployment that conatains that service can be found [here](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/#bare-metal).

If you wish to skip the ingress you might be just using the `nodePort` service  `awx` and reach it directly.

Answer (score 1):

I am using Kubernetes 1.22 and the operator version 0.14.0.

I have a Kubernetes baremetal installation and I have to use ingress. The ingress provided with the operator is not compatible with the version of kubernetes I am using so I had to define it myself.
I am using Ansible but you could work out the values for the variables :)

```
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: {{ awx_deployment_name }}-ingress-unmanaged
  namespace: {{ awx_namespace }}
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-read-timeout: "3600"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-send-timeout: "3600"
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
  - host: {{ awx_host }}
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: {{ awx_deployment_name }}-service
            port:
              number: 80
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - {{ awx_host }}
    secretName: {{ awx_tls_secret}}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can simply expose the deployment to a service type `LoadBalancer`

the following command creates a service with a type loadBalancer

kubectl expose deployment awx-demo --port=80 --target-port=8052 --name=awx-lb --type=LoadBalancer

Comment: I tried this and then I see this: `service/awx-lb                                            LoadBalancer   10.43.217.56   <pending>     80:31572/TCP   53s` and the <pending> never changes to an ip.